# Goldbach's conjecture and how to express it formally

Tags: logic, goldbachs-conjecture

Goldbach's conjecture states that

$$\text{Every even integer greater than 2 is the sum of two primes}$$

Is it true to say that Goldbach's conjecture is formally claiming that:

$$\forall 2(k+1),\exists\; p_1,p_2 \in \mathbb P:k \in \mathbb N^+ \implies 2(k+1)=p_1+p_2$$

Or $$\forall n \in \mathbb E,,\exists\; p_1,p_2 \in \mathbb P: n=p_1+p_2$$
Where $$\mathbb E:=\left\{n:n=2(k+1), k\in \mathbb N^+\right\}$$

And $\mathbb P$ is the set of prime numbers.

Answer (score 2):

$\forall 2(k+1)$ is not a correct logical formulation. You could write instead
$$
\forall\ k \in {\Bbb N}-\{0,1\}\ \exists\ p_1, p_2 \in {\Bbb P}\quad 2k = p_1 + p_2
$$
But of course, the original formulation without any logical symbol is highly preferable.

Comment: The other is essentially correct, but I would get rid of the first two commas (after $\Bbb E$) and the columns. Moreover, I would define $\Bbb E$ as follows: ${\Bbb E} = \{ n \in {\Bbb N} \mid \exists k \in {\Bbb N}\ k \geqslant 2 \text{ and } n = 2k\}$ or simply say "where $E$ is the set of even integers $\geqslant 4$".